# When are parenthesis required to prevent PHP notice in PHP IF clause?

Tags: php

I would have expected `$x->p` never to be resolved as the first condition `!$x=getIt()` is true, yet this is not the case for the first two examples.

When are parenthesis required in IF clause?

```
<?php

  if(!$x=getIt() || ($x->p) ){echo('yes1');}
  else {echo('no1');}

  if(!$x=getIt() || $x->p ){echo('yes2');}
  else {echo('no2');}

  if(!($x=getIt()) || ($x->p) ){echo('yes3');}
  else {echo('no3');}

  if(!($x=getIt()) || $x->p ){echo('yes4');}
  else {echo('no4');}

  function getIt(){return false;}
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Notice: Undefined variable: x in /var/www/html/test.php on line 3

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/test.php on line 3
yes1
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/test.php on line 6
yes2yes3yes4
```

Comment: *When are parenthesis required in IF clause?* short answer: **never**

Comment: You need to look at the PHP operator precedence table.

Comment: @Rizier123  Yet I receive a notice when not used.  I'll post results.

Comment: as previosly said no need in this case. you may need it if you do an expression, like if((i+1) == j)

Comment: Notice is no error. It says you should declare your variables first, which is generally advisable to prevent strange errors. Also it was a former security issue, or is if you have a dangerous php.ini configuration. $x->p is not defined and won't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical operator `||` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. So

```
!$x = getIt() || $x->p
```

is treated like:

```
!$x = (getIt() || $x->p)
```

When `getIt()` returns a falsy value, this will access the property of `$x` before the variable is assigned, and before the result is inverted by `!`.

You need parentheses to override this precedence. You could also use `or` instead of `||`, because it has lower precedence.

```
if (!$x = getIt() or $x->p)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thank you

Comment: And I take it the parenthesis given it higher precedence than `||`?

Comment: Parentheses override all precedences.

Comment: I see you already answered my second comment.  Also, I never new `or` was any different than `||`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it is good habit to always use it. You definitely will thank yourself as soon as you get into using languages with preprocessor.

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the direct question *"when is it required"* nor does it explain the observed behaviour. 2) It's unclear what this has to do with preprocessed languages.

Comment: ok, i could perhaps agree with 1) yet it does not render my answer incorrect which usually downvote should be for. As for 2) - you can have i.e. `#define` that will completely change your condition. It's even more painful when one not uses `{}` even for one liners, then such macro, especially when unfolds to multiple lines, can wreck havoc

Answer (score 0):

I use the braces for the following reason

- They reduce the work required to understand the code.
- They provide confirmation of the developer's intent.

Answer (score -1):

Notice is no error.

The first notice says variable x is not declared (So you never assigned it before)

The others just inform you nicely that $x->p does nothing, because $x is no object and therefore has no properties

For the brackets question see other answers

Comment: Agree it is not an error, but wish to know why I received a notice.  `if(!$x=getIt() ){echo('yes0');}` does not do so.  Why did `$x->p` ever get checked if the first condition is true?

Comment: cause you assign $x to false in fist step. but a boolean is no object. the "->" tries to access a object property  (you may see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php to understand what the -> does)

Comment: ... and see the answer of Barmar to understand why not every line does the same notice.

Answer (score -1):

As said by Marcin, it is a good habit to use them always. 
But in php, if the the IF statement body is single line, then it is not necessary to use parenthesis. See below example:

```
if(your condition)
   some php code here;
```

The above example is fine and will work.

Now if the body of IF statement has multiple lines of code, then you have to use parenthesis. Check below example.

```
if(your condition) {
   some php code here; 
   some more code here;
   ....
}
```

Now in above case, parenthesis are required. 
If parenthesis are not used in above, you wont get your expected results or you will get an error.

Thanks